# Finding directories which files explicitly contain escape signs like ] , - Space all together

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, find, escape-characters

I have several video files, which contain escape characters like [ in combination with [1920x1080]. When I execute:

```
find /run/media/user/usbdisk -type f -iname [HD, 1920x1080] - Wild Wild West.mp4 -ls
```

then I receive an error like this:

```
find:paths must precede expression
```

When I execute

```
find /run/media/user/usbdisk -type f -iname "[HD, 1920x1080] - Wild Wild West.mp4" -ls
```

the I get NO result, though I'm sure, the file exist.

Same result (nothing found) when execute:

```
find /run/media/user/usbdisk -type f -iname '[HD, 1920x1080] - Wild Wild West.mp4' -ls
```

To receive the directory name (basename) of my movie, I have stored the name in a variable named video, so that my command finally looks like this:

```
dname=$(find /run/media/user/usbdisk -type f -iname "$video" -exec dirname {} \;)
```

but this leads to error result (see above).

How can I make the command find (or any else) to exactly find my exact named file including escape signs? 
Is there any way or is it necessary to substitute the escape signs in the file names? I want prevent this.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try to escape those escape characters? At least that's marked as the solution for [How to find files by names which contains brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15928827/how-to-find-files-by-names-which-contains-brackets). As you are using a pattern to match you will likely have to escape those characters.

Answer (score 1):

`-iname` evaluates its argument, `*`,`?` and `[]` have special meaning to it, so you have to escape them if you want to pass them literally.

Also consider using `-quit` in case you otherwise find two or more files in different folders (duplicates?). I guess you expect `dname` to be a single directory name.

I understand `$video` is already given:

```
video="[HD, 1920x1080] - Wild Wild West.mp4"
```

In this case try:

```
video1=$(echo $video | sed 's|\[|\\[|g; s|\]|\\]|g')
dname=$(find /run/media/user/usbdisk -type f -iname "$video1" -exec dirname {} \; -quit)
```

It can be done in one line. I chose to introduce additional variable for clarity.

Comment: Thanks first. The point is, the (movie) names are fixed, preset. I can't add a \ to pass escape special characters. I simply want to pass the content of a variable (here $video) no matter what it contains.
And yes, $dname should contain the directory's name, where the video is found.

Comment: @Linuxwhisperer I have adjusted my answer to your needs.

Comment: I tried - no result...

Comment: @Linuxwhisperer It works in my Kubuntu. Just to make sure: you didn't expect `dname=…` to return something, you checked `echo $dname` after, right? Can you give me any feedback? (e.g. "it works with such-and-such filename but not with…" or "`video1` doesn't seem right because…").

Comment: sorry for late reply. I had to try again, copy and paste and adopt... Now you way seems to work. I will make more testings in my scripts now.
Thanks again!

Comment: @Linuxwhisperer To tell the truth, there was a bug in `video1=…` line, I fixed it just after I published it. You must have been fast enough to copy the bugged version. Sorry for that.